# pip install scipy on virtualenv error RHEL6.5

Tags: scipy, pip, virtualenv

I have already consulted these among other non stack overflow sources:
[Install line 'pip install scipy' fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648130/pip-install-scipy-fails)

[Installing SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip)

[install scipy using pip in virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093058/install-scipy-using-pip-in-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-12-04)

[Installing SciPy on Red Hat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796138/installing-scipy-on-red-hat)

RHEL6.5 distro comes with python2.6 I have installed virtualenv and  python2.7. Installing packages (within my virtualenv i.e. after activating it with `source MyEnvs/myEnv1/bin/activate`) with: `pip install {package name}` and can verify, using `yolk -l` that my environment has the the packages I want. All was find until I tried `pip install scipy` I get the following error:

[~]# pip install scipy
Downloading/unpacking scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.14.0.tar.gz (10.2MB): 10.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py) egg_info for package scipy

```
warning: no previously-included files matching '*_subr_*.f' found under directory 'scipy/linalg/src/id_dist/src'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy/special/tests/data/boost'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy/special/tests/data/gsl'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/source/generated'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/__pycache__'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
```

Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

```
openblas_info:
  libraries  not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
  NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 234, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 173, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/setup.py", line 12, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('integrate')
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 12, in configuration
    blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 350, in get_info
    return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
  File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 509, in get_info
    raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
Complete output from command /root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mun5c1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/include/site/python2.7:
blas_opt_info:
```

blas_mkl_info:

libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:

libraries  not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:

```
Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

the ATLAS environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)

blas_info:

libraries blas not found in ['/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

the BLAS environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.**doc**)

blas_src_info:

NOT AVAILABLE

/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in

```
setup_package()
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 234, in setup_package

```
setup(**metadata)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup

```
config = configuration()
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py", line 173, in configuration

```
config.add_subpackage('scipy')
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage

```
caller_level = 2)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage

```
caller_level = caller_level + 1)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

```
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
```

File "scipy/setup.py", line 12, in configuration

```
config.add_subpackage('integrate')
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 966, in add_subpackage

```
caller_level = 2)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 935, in get_subpackage

```
caller_level = caller_level + 1)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 872, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

```
config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
```

File "scipy/integrate/setup.py", line 12, in configuration

```
blas_opt = get_info('blas_opt',notfound_action=2)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 350, in get_info

```
return cl().get_info(notfound_action)
```

File "/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py", line 509, in get_info

```
raise self.notfounderror(self.notfounderror.__doc__)
```

numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

the BLAS environment variable.
```

---

Cleaning up...
Command /root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mun5c1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /root/PythonVirtualEnvs/env1/build/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

I verified that scipy, atlas, blas have been installed through yum. I am not sure where to go from here, I would like to find a solution that uses pip, i.e. I don't want to do `easy_install scipy` Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by installing following packages:

1. sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
2. sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran

then install numpy or scipy and any other tools via

```
pip install <package--name> inside your virtualenv
```